# Truncate stdout of subprocess.run() without shell=True

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running a binary executable from Python using the `subprocess.run()` command and the command spits out about 20MB of text data to stdout. I'm only interested in the first few lines of the output and loading the entire output of the command into the memory takes a very long time (about 10 seconds).

I would like to read stdout of the command up the 10th line and then truncate all other output. What I would like to achieve is the equivalend of running `command | head` (which is super fast), but I have the `shell=False` set which does not allow the use of pipes.

Is there any way I can truncate the output of stdout to just a few lines/bytes without loading it all into memory? I already tried the `bufsize=` parameter, but it had no effect.

Comment: All `head` does is read the given number of lines from the process's stdout and then exit (whereafter the program on the left hand of the pipeline gets a SIGPIPE next time it tries to write to its stdout, and thus typically will thereafter exit as well). You can, of course, do that yourself -- in your Python code.

Comment: ...which is to say: I'd have to see your specific code using `subprocess` to know _why_ it's loading all of stdout into memory. That's not unconditional/automatic/default behavior, unless you're using something like `communicate()`, which is explicitly defined to do so.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the behaviour of `head` to me. I think in my case the problem is not that the entire thing is in the memory, but the problem is that `head` manages to kill the command after it spits out 10 lines, but subprocess will wait until the command finishes fully.

Comment: I wish there was a way to recreate what `head` does the way you explained it above

Comment: `head` does not actually kill the program; all it does is close the output side of the FIFO (implicitly, by exiting), the program kills itself when its next attempt to write something to stdout fails. The sending-a-SIGPIPE is done automatically, by the operating system when there's a `read` syscall after the writer closed their end, or a `write` syscall after the reader closed _their_ end.

Comment: ...so, if you added a `p.stdout.close()` after the loop in @orlevii's code, that would close (at least most of) the gap in behavior between what their code does and what piping to head does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `subprocess.Popen` you can have access to the subprocess's stdout and read as many lines as you want

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

lines_to_read = 10

for i in range(lines_to_read):
    print(p.stdout.readline())
```

Comment: This still loads it all into memory and takes about 10 seconds for my command as opposed to the `command | head` command that takes ~100ms

Comment: 10 seconds for it to reach what point? The end of the loop, or are you waiting for something additional to happen after the loop has ended? (If you put a `p.wait()` in there, f/e, it could well end up hanging indefinitely, since the child process would still be hanging waiting for its output to be read).

Comment: @TadejMagajna, ...btw, did you accept this after confirming that putting `p.stdout.close()` after the loop works? (If so, that might be worth noting so that explicit close can be added to the answer).

Comment: No, I accepted this after actually running the code (I was initially convinced that the approach above would not work before actually running it). Works great - thanks to both of you!